# Kotlin: call List and Grid recycleView in fragment

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

I want to make a button with ImageView in Fragment that can show Grid and List RecycleView data, but when I use this code when I press the image my app suddenly force close.

logcat error is: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property rvFavorite has not been initialized

the code that make error:

```
rvFavorite.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
```

```
class FavoriteFragment : Fragment() { ...
```

```
... showRecyclerview()
```

Here my fragment code:

```
class FavoriteFragment : Fragment() {

    private val list: ArrayList<ProductsResult> = arrayListOf()
    private lateinit var rvFavorite: RecyclerView


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        iv_action_favorites_list.setOnClickListener {
            showRecyclerview()
        }
        iv_action_favorites_grid.setOnClickListener {
            showGridRecyclerview()
        }
        fetchFavorite()
    }

   

    private fun getImage(imageName: String): Int {
        return resources.getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", context?.packageName)
    }


    private fun showRecyclerview() {
        rvFavorite.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
        val FavoriteListAdapter = FavoriteListAdapter(list)
        rvFavorite.adapter = FavoriteListAdapter
    }


    private fun showGridRecyclerview() {
        rvFavorite.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this.context, 2)
        val FavoriteGridAdapter = FavoriteGridAdapter(list)
        rvFavorite.adapter = FavoriteGridAdapter
    }
}
```

Comment: in the log, what line does it say is causing the error?

Comment: @beastlyCoder there 3 line that causing the error,
``` rvFavorite.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context) ```
``` class FavoriteFragment : Fragment() { ...  ```
```  ... showRecyclerview() ```

Comment: could you add the log to your post so we could diagnose it

Comment: @beastlyCoder okay, thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem, these the answer:
you have to initialized `private lateinit var rvFavorite: RecyclerView` with init View ex: `findViewById` or you just have to call the RecyclerView's ID.